# AWS Codebuild error in DOWNLOAD_SOURCE Phase

Tags: git, aws-codebuild

I have an issue with codebuild which i do not understand correctly.

Codebuild is passing all phases until

**DOWNLOAD_SOURCE**

[image: Error description]

And i am not understanding what this error wants to tell me:

CLIENT_ERROR: mkdir /codebuild/output/srcDownload/src/.git/refs/remotes/origin/release: **not a directory for primary source and source version** refs/heads/tests/request-midwife-flow

Is this a git error, or an error in downloading source files at codebuild ?
Do i need to specify **primary source** or **source version** anywhere?

I appreciate good reads also about this, since i have not experienced this error before.

thanks!
patrick

Answer (score 1):

Ok so if anyone ever runs into this issue:

I investigated the repo's branches and found a branch named `release`.
Since there was also a release planned opening up a branch `release/some-branch-name` we ran into the error message mentioned above.

Basically i understand it this way, that a branch-name can not be a "folder" for other branches like in a filesystem where a file can not be named as equally to a folder.

Hard learning....

I removed the branch named `release` and we got back to normal.

Cheers